# React dependency in react-native module's podspec

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, cocoapods

I'm looking at [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-React-Native) of Microsoft's Mobile center SDK for react-native. There are several native modules for react-native, and the recommended way to install them is via Cocoapods.

Now, each module has podspec, but none mention `React` as dependency. For example, `appcenter-crashes.podspec` has these dependencies:

```
s.dependency 'AppCenterReactNativeShared'
s.dependency 'AppCenter/Crashes'
```

And `AppCenterReactNativeShared.podspec` has just

```
s.dependency 'AppCenter/Core', '1.1.0'
```

Yet the module are react-native bridges and depend on `React` and import from `React` in their sources. For example, `AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.m` has these lines:

```
#import "AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h"

// Support React Native headers both in the React namespace, where they are in RN version 0.40+,
// and no namespace, for older versions of React Native
#if __has_include(<React/RCTAssert.h>)
#import <React/RCTAssert.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
...
```

Next, in my react-native project I can link mobile center and build and run my app with Podfile like this:

```
target 'example' do
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.0.1'
end
```

Again, I don't need to mention `React` pod and its subspecs here!

Now in my own react-native native module I have to declare dependencies like:

```
s.dependency 'React'
s.dependency 'some-other-dependency-my-module-needs'
```

And then in my app's `Podfile` I have include `React` pod:

```
pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
  'Core',
  'RCTActionSheet',
...
```

If I don't include `React` in native module podspec then I get error `fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found`. If I don't add `React` to Pofile, then Cocoapods drags deprecated React pod from its repository and the build breaks.

So, my question is how is it possible that mobile center native modules do not have `React` in their podspecs and how can I get rid of it in my native module?

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain how "greenfield" (react native app created from scratch) and "brownfield" (existing Objective-C/Swift app migrated to react native) iOS apps work for [App Center React Native SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-React-Native).

For "greenfield" React Native app created from scratch, whether it is created via `react-native init {myapp}` or via `create-react-native-app {myapp}`, `react` and `react-native` dependencies are added automatic during the creation and referenced in your `package.json`.

For "brownfield" React Native app, assuming you followed the React Native [Integration with Existing Apps documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) to convert your Objective-C/Swift app into React Native, you need to reference `React` dependencies in your `Podfile` like the example in [Configuring CocoaPods dependencies](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies):

```
# The target name is most likely the name of your project.
target 'NumberTileGame' do

  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'GLog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

end
```

You can take a look at the [`Podfile`](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-React-Native/blob/1.1.0/BrownfieldTestApp/ios/Podfile) of the sample "brownfield" app in App Center SDK. In this example, `React` is reference in the `Podfile` and it is required for the brownfield app to find react references. In other words, without `React` reference in `Podfile`, you will see errors similar to `fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found`.

Comment: Thank you. My app is greenfield (created in RN from scratch), but it has native dependencies - some native modules like `react-native-maps`, `react-native-config`, and AppCenter is one of those deps. When I do `react-native` link, some of the deps are added directly to xcode project, and since RN0.51 those which have podspec will be instead added to Podfile. So I have an app with podfile like [this](https://gist.github.com/doomsower/8632d3ff348f1db456a5c0998f843704) - without React and subspecs. And it builds and runs. But for my module I have to add React to Podfile. How is this?

Comment: For greenfield ios app, `React` dependency is referenced via `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` to your local `node_modules/react-native` path. For example, App Center `AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics` native module reference `React` in `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(SRCROOT)/../../react-native/React/**";` at [this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-React-Native/blob/master/appcenter-analytics/ios/AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj#L237). In other words, if `React` is not present in the Header Search Path, the native module won't find `React` and consequently throw an error.

Comment: @KonstantinKuznetsov, you should double check if `react` is properly referenced in the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` of your native module.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [App Center SDK documentation for React Native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native), you have to run `react-native link` which will add the native dependencies for React Native for iOS.

The react-native version is actually defined in `package.json` at Javascript level and `react-native link` will install the corresponding native dependencies for that version.

Also when we make changes to the SDK, we use a test app to host the project so we can edit both test application and SDK code in the same XCode workspace.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand what is going on during `react-native link` - prelink, postlink, inquirer asks your keys, Podile and AppDelegate are modified, `pod install` runs. As far as I get it, in RN0.51 all the native iOS dependencies of AppCenter (and as a react bridge it depends on `React` pod) are managed by Cocoapods. The part that I don't understand is that `React` pod is never mentioned in AppCenter podspecs. During build process AppCenter (or app using AppCenter) somehow satisfies AppCenter's dependency on native part of RN, but I'm unable to achieve same for my native module.